# Tableau Usage Analytics Report- How to find total users who has access to tableau reports

Tags: excel, report, tableau-api, analytics, tableau-desktop

I have a tableau usage analytics report which tells me the number of users who did something(the numerator) but not the total number of users who has access to do something(the denominator) or the total number of users who could have used the reports.

How can I add total number of users who could have used the reports to the workbook?

Number of users are calculated as COUNTD([USER_ID])

and If am if I am using the calculated field for total users -

{ FIXED year([he_created_at (EST)]):countd([USER_ID])}

Would it suffice?

Comment: You would get this info from your Tableau Server's Users and or Groups page/s. Not entirely sure how to pull this info dynamically. A good problem, I will look into this further.